# vsftpd won't auto start on boot with pasv_addr_resolve=YES

Tags: 18.04, autostart, vsftpd

Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS

vsftpd 3.0.3

(Sorry for my bad English)

vsftpd won't auto start on boot if I set "pasv_address=example.com" and "pasv_addr_resolve=YES".

Manual start is fine when after booted.

And, auto start on boot works fine if I set with Public IP address "pasv_address=123.45.67.89".

My computer is behind router.

How can I fix it?
Would you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this for more than 4 hours and reading every single question about it to no avail (:P) I figured it out thanks to an old post and decided to create an account to share (more of a workaround as I guess this is an actual bug)

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service`

Add under

```
[Service]
Type=simple
```

these 2 lines:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
```

Done :)